# How to add Serial Port Profile v1.2 in Bluez v5.5?

Tags: bluetooth, yocto, spp

My OS is Yocto (2.4 rock).
I checked to Bluez website, it supports spp(Serial Port Profile) v1.1.

I need to update it to v1.2 for Bluetooth certification, how to implement it?

By the way, both WIN 10 and Android Q support spp v1.2.

If you have any ideas, please let me know.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you really mean `v5.5` that was released before the SPP 1.2 spec was? Or do you mean `v5.50` which does support SPP 1.2? https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/supported-features.txt?h=5.50#n17

Comment: I checked the wetsite http://www.bluez.org/profiles/
It lists all profiles bluez has supported. The spp version is v1.1.

Comment: I personally would trust the document in the source repository more than the website, but you are correct, there is a discrepancy. Maybe drop an email to the [mailing list](http://www.bluez.org/development/lists/) to clarify the situation.